# Unity: Positioning square tiles on board using Rect Transform

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a simple 2D grid of square tiles, each 1x1 unit in size.

The GameObject representing the board has a Rect Transform set up [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMtLC.png).
`4` is just a placeholder - I'm resizing it in C# because I don't know the board size at compile-time. The goal was to lock the board's center in place, even after a resize, and this appears to work.

I am having trouble getting the tiles to work properly, though. I have anchored a test tile to the top left of the board. When I set `Pos X = 0, Pos Y = 0`, the *center* of the tile aligns to the top left of the board, [causing overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ws3Sj.png).

Can I somehow change the position's "reference point" within the tile to its upper left corner so that `Pos X = 0, Pos Y = 0` will position the tile where I want it (its upper left corner is at the anchor)?

I'd like to avoid adding that offset in code if possible.

Comment: If you change the anchor of the tile to be Top-Left, then the (0,0) position will be the top left.  Currently the anchor is in the center of the tile, so when you place the tile at the board (0,0) position, it places the tile anchor (halfWidth, halfHeight) at (0,0) of the board.  You could also offset the width and height by half if you want to keep the pivot centered on the tile.

Comment: @hijinxbassist Where/how do I change the anchor of the tile itself?

Comment: There should be a visual anchors box on the top left of RectTransform component.  Click there and select one of the visual anchors.  This link should be helpful, [UI Basic Layout](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/UIBasicLayout.html)